# Laravel how to validation with unique JSON fields type?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7, laravel-validation

I have a POST endpoint on my Laravel 5.7 API and Mariadb 10.3, I used postman to test my route and here is the problem. I want to send an array of the same kind of object, like this :

```
{  
   "Shops":[  
   {
     "name": {
        "en":"ShopEng",
        "es":"ShopESP"
      },
    "code": "0891"
   }
   ]
}
```

In my database.I have Shops table and Name field as JSON type.

```
{"en":"TestEng","es":"TestESP"}
```

In my Request. I also tried with the simple but not work.

```
public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            'Shops'         => 'required|array',
            'Shops.*.name.en' => 'required|unique:shops,name->en',
            'Shops.*.name.es' => 'required|unique:shops,name->es',
            'Shops.*.code'        => 'required|integer'
        );

    }
```

With Message.

```
"message": "Method Illuminate\\Validation\\Validator::validateUnique,shops,name>en does not exist.",
"exception": "BadMethodCallException",
"file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php",
```

Comment: Can you provide the error message please?

Comment: are you passing the array `Shops`? because you're using `Shop` without 's'

Comment: @Shaikot Thank you very much. I added it for you.

Comment: I am not sure, can you try name[en] rather then name->en?

Comment: @Shaikot I tried but still not working. 
With message.
"message": "Method Illuminate\\Validation\\Validator::validateUnique,shops,name[en] does not exist.",

Comment: unique:shops.name->en or unique:shops.name,en  try one more time please

Comment: @Shaikot Thank sir, but not work again with message.
    "message": "Database [shops] not configured.",
    "exception": "InvalidArgumentException",
I will try to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The [second parameter written in the unique validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-unique) refers to a column on the database table where the unique rule will be tested, I'm afraid the syntax you wrote there is not valid.

My guess here is that you will have yo create a [custom validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#custom-validation-rules) for handling this particular case.